# servlet is not redirecting to new page

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

i submit values in `alter.jsp` and get them in a servlet `changeServlet.java`.

alter.jsp-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Department Creation</title>
    <style>
        a:link, a:visited {
            background-color:darkolivegreen;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 25px;
            text-align: center;
            width:100px; 
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius:20px; 
        }


        a:hover, a:active {
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
        header {
            background-color:teal;
            color:white;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
        nav {
            line-height:30px;
            height:300px;
            width:100px;
            float:left;
            padding:45px;
        }
        section {
            height:270px; 
            width:550px;
            float:right;
            padding:150px;
        }
        footer {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
            clear:both;
            text-align:center;
            padding:5px;
        }
        #depart {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;

        }

        #depart td, #depart th {
            border: 2px solid black;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;                
        }            

        #depart tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;} 

        #depart th {
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 12px;
            background-color: lightslategray;
            color: white;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightsteelblue;"> 
    <%
        String userName = null;
        String sessionID = null;
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if (cookie.getName().equals("admin")) {
                    userName = cookie.getValue();
                }
            }
        }
    %>
    <header>
        <h1>File Tracking System</h1>
        <div><span style="float:right">Hi <%=userName%></span></div> 
        <br>  
        <form style="float:right;" action=" LogoutServlet" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Logout" >
        </form>      
        <br>
    </header>
    <br>
    <a href="department.jsp"><font color="white">1.Create Department</font></a>
    <a href="c_user.jsp"><font color="white">2.Enter User Details</font></a>
    <a href="seeuserdetails.jsp"><font color="white">3.See User Details</font></a>
    <br>
```

Here i am submitting values , action is changeServlet

```
    <nav>
        <form action="changeServlet" method="post">
            <center>                
            <table id="depart">  
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Change user detail</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>User Name :</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="user" value="" size="50"    /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Column Entry</td>
                        <td><select name="column">
                                <option>username</option>
                                <option>password</option>
                                <option>role</option>
                                <option>firstname</option>
                                <option>lastname</option>
                                <option>departmentname</option>
                                <option>email</option>
                                <option>mobile</option>
                            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>New data:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="data" value="" size="50"   /></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
            <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Clear" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
        </form>
    </nav>
    <section><img src="css/NSIC-logo1.png" width="537" height="267" alt="NSIC-logo1"/>
    </section>
    <br>
    <footer>
        Copyright 2016 NSIC. All right reserved.   
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the values in `changeServlet.java` but it does not show any error and is not getting redirected anywhere it is simply opening `http://localhost:8080/test9/changeServlet` and is stuck here showing a white blank page

changeServlet.java

```
package bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class changeServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
//request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies != null){
for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
    if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")){
        System.out.println("JSESSIONID="+cookie.getValue());
        break;
    }
}
}       
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
System.out.println("admin="+session.getAttribute("admin"));
if(session!=null && session.getAttribute("admin") != null){
           String admin=(String)session.getAttribute("admin"); 
            boolean status=false;
try{
    String user=request.getParameter("user");
    String column=request.getParameter("column");
    String data=request.getParameter("data");            
    boolean checkc=checkchar.value(column);
    boolean checkp=checkchar.value(data);
```

the if statement is checking for any wrong entry or null value when submit wrong entry it redirects to entry.jsp. This means it is working till here but after this not working.

```
 if(checkc==true&&checkp==true) {
    Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
    String sql="update usertable set '"+column+"'='"+data+"' where username='"+user+"'";
    PreparedStatement pstmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);

    int rs=pstmt.executeUpdate();
    if(rs>0){status=true;}

        if(status){

              response.sendRedirect("updated.jsp");
                    }
          else 
          {   

              response.sendRedirect("notinsert.jsp");
          }
        }
    else{response.sendRedirect("entry.jsp");}
        }catch(SQLException e){}  
          }else{
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
rd.include(request, response);
}
}
}
```

Comment: You can't write to a response and then send a redirect.  A redirect is in the header.  If you write to the response you've already finalized the header.

Comment: i don't understand could you explain a little more

Comment: you get the `PrintWriter` from the `response` and then write to it.  Then you send a redirect.  This doesn't work.  Remove the interaction with the `PrintWriter` and it should work.

Comment: i have removed it but it still doesn't work

Comment: give reason for down vote?